# How to compile SharpSVN and SvnQuery

Tags: sharpsvn

I'm trying to compile the SvnQuery project (https://github.com/kalyptorisk/svnquery.git) with the a version SharpSVN.dll which I created on my PC, but I keep seeing the error message *CS0400: The type or namespace name 'SharpSvn' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)*.

Using the SharpSVN.dll which comes with the SvnQuery source code, I do not see this error message, nor any other.

Both SharpSVN.dll files look the same when I open them in .NET Reflector, but there is one difference - the file which I created doesn't have version information. (To be exact: When you look at the file's properties in File Explorer, "File version" and "Product version" are empty.)

I followed these steps to create SharpSVN.dll:

Check out from https://ctf.open.collab.net/svn/repos/sharpsvn (tried trunk and the 1.1200x branch). Open VisualStudio command prompt (tried 2012, 2015 and 2017), cd to 'imports' folder, run 'nant build'. Result: no errors, but this doesn't create SharpSVN.dll (and I guess it shouldn't).

Now double-click SharpSvn.sln in the src folder. This opens VS2017. Compile Release|x86. Result: no errors, many warnings, SharpSVN.dll (with no version information) created in src\SharpSvn\bin\Win32\Release.

Any ideas about this issue?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. My problem has nothing to do with the missing version number. In fact, I had compiled SharpSVN for a .NET version higher than that of the SvnQuery project. After increasing the .NET version number for SvnQuery and related projects, all compiled well. And SvnIndex.exe seems to run smoothly (test still ongoing).